# Custom ViewPager inside ObservableScrollView not measuring Height Properly

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have a `CustomViewPager` inside an `ObservableScrollView` which looks like this:

[image]

It seems to measure the fragment but does not measure the height of the fragment which is off the screen. So I can't actually scroll up.

This is the code for the CustomViewPager:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

private View view;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    boolean wrapHeight = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST;

    View tab = getChildAt(getCurrentItem());
    int width = getMeasuredWidth();
    int tabHeight = tab.getMeasuredHeight();

    if (wrapHeight) {
        // Keep the current measured width.
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }

    int fragmentHeight = measureFragment(((Fragment) getAdapter().instantiateItem(this, getCurrentItem())).getView());
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(tabHeight + fragmentHeight + (int)
            TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public int measureFragment(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return 0;

    view.measure(0, 0);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}

}
```

**NOTE:** If I add say `+ 1000` to `heightMeasureSpec` in `super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);` then I can scroll the size of the fragment as well as any extra space. But obviously this is not a preferred solution.

Here is my XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoBox"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp">

    <!-- Code for other views -->

</LinearLayout>

<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.ui.customviewpager.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>
```

What seems to be the issue here? It seems like I am not the only one with this issue.

I implemented some of this design from this link [here](http://www.henning.ms/2013/09/09/viewpager-that-simply-dont-measure-up/)

Comment: Is it necessary to override onMeasure here? There's a chance your fragment hasn't been inflated at the time onMeasure is called in your viewpager, so the height is returning 0.
in your layout, try setting the height of your viewpager to match_parent, and same with the linearlayout containing it. Is it even necessary to have that linearlayout?

Comment: I believe the custom class ObservableScrollView insists that you must have a child layout inside the scrollview otherwise it would not work properly. What would you suggest I do here?

Comment: cool cool. is [this](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) the library you're using? Gimme a chance to check it out some more after work to understand how that works better. I noticed the sample app provided by that library seems to have a [viewpager example](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/samples/res/layout/activity_flexiblespacewithimagewithviewpagertab2.xml) using framelayouts.

In the meantime, does the library insist on having wrap_content set as the height? Could you try setting those to match_parent to see if that helps?

Comment: Yes you're correct hhoang. Your name sounds familiar, for some reason I keep thinking you made the material tabs repository.

Answer (score 4):

ScrollView child should not have margin for the scrollView to display properly.
It seems that the margin is not taken into account when the scrollView measure its child.

Try removing margin of LinearLayout (you can use padding to reproduce the effect).

Comment: if I use padding how can I make sure it scroll up properly?

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you use ObservableScrollView  inside the fragment and put the viewpager inside a TouchInterceptionFrameLayout (from the same lib), then  set setTouchInterceptionViewGroup of the ObservableScrollView  to be the one containing your viewpager and do the logic on the TouchInterceptionListener in your activity to either move it up and down with with animation in order to mimic a smooth scrolling effect.

I hope that is that your are looking for to achieve and hopefully it will help you.

Ps: See the guy example app and source ([Link](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)), it is a bit complex but im sure you will find something.

Comment: One of the concerns with that is that his flexible space image parallax with viewpager tabs activity does not function well.

Comment: it does work well... or what do you mean by does not work well ?

Comment: I have been using that library the problem is that when your header contains a picture, other layouts, and when you have three fragments which contain a recyclerview, RecyclerView, and a grid view respectively which is all loaded from an API then I run into issues. How exactly do you propose I solve this can you provide a solution or layout for a solution. I have looked at all of the samples of his library

Comment: First please provide me more information on what you are trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1):

Hello i am not much aware of ObservableScrollView but according to your problem you are not able to find out height of fragment. After searching a lot i am able to find out tutorial  to get the height of fragments.

here is the link
http://adanware.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-getting-measuring-fragment.html

Hope, this will help you.